# Relationship between completely continuous operators and uniformly continuous operators

Tags: functional-analysis

suppose T : X -> Y is a (maybe nonlinear) completely continuous operator, where X and Y are Banach spaces (reflexive, if necessary). Is it true that T is a uniformly continuous operator? Or a weaker assertion: Is true that T is uniformly continuous on bounded sets?
Thanks! 
Uriel

Comment: Completely continuous = continuous + maps bounded sets to compact sets?

Comment: Amsmath, by completely continuous I mean continuous + images of bounded sets have compact closures.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry, that's what I meant,

Comment: Well, if $T$ may be nonlinear, then we can forget the linear structures on $X$ and $Y$, and talk about complete metric spaces..

Comment: Many things are easier in Banach spaces than in complete metric spaces, and my interest is in fact with a nonlinear operator acting between Banach spaces, but, I don´t mind if the answer is "yes" in complete metric spaces. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No to both questions. First one is easy: take $x \mapsto x^2$ from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

For the second example, take $X = l^2$ and $Y = \mathbb{C}$. Let $T(e_n) = 1$ and $T(\frac{n-1}{n}e_n)=0$. Note that all those pairs of points $e_n, \frac{n-1}{n}e_n$ are separated from other pairs by at least $1/2$. That means you can extend $T$ to the whole space continuously and in such a way that $\mathrm{Im} \, T = [0, 1]$.

Comment: Thanks! Does it change something if the spaces over the real field, and T is monotone?

Comment: @uriel, Well, the answer to the first question doesn't change ($x \mapsto x^3$ in $\mathbb{R}$). The second is much better and I'm afraid I don't know. Perhaps you should make a new question, possibly on mathoverflow (if you think your question is deep enough).